# flutter how to generate random numbers without duplication

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to generate random numbers without duplication?
For instance I want to generate 50 random numbers from 1 to 100 no duplication, any way to do this or do I have to check every time incoming number is already created or not?

Comment: If it's only small range of integer you can use hash table to keep all free number. Then pop it out at random index.

Comment: you can create an array of integer with 1 to 100 number and shuffle it using shuffle  method and used as much as number you require.

Comment: shuffle sounds good to me. Is it not generating same number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use shuffle as following code.

```
import 'dart:math';

var list = new List<int>.generate(10, (int index) => index); // [0, 1, 4]
list.shuffle();
print(list);
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. Can I get first 5 shuffled numbers?

Comment: you can get using list.sublist(0,5).

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Set*. Each object can occur only once when using it. Just try this:

```
Set<int> setOfInts = Set();
while (setOfInts.length < 50) {
  setOfInts.add(Random().nextInt(range) + 1);
}
```

You can read the documentation here: [Set Doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Set-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that avoids creating an array of all the possible values, and avoids repeatedly looping until no collision occurs. It may be useful when there is a large range to select from.

```
import 'dart:math';

class RandomList {
  static final _random = new Random();

  static List<int> uniqueSample({int limit, int n}) {
    final List<int> sortedResult = [];
    final List<int> result = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      int rn = _random.nextInt(limit - i); // We select from a smaller list of available numbers each time

      // Increment the number so that it picks from the remaining list of available numbers
      int j = 0;
      for (; j < sortedResult.length && sortedResult[j] <= rn; j++) rn++;

      sortedResult.insert(j, rn);
      result.add(rn);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

I haven't tested it exhaustively but it seems to work.